# How to use two different versions of library in google colab?

Tags: python, anaconda, google-colaboratory, sklearn-pandas

How to use two different versions of library (for example, sklearn) in google colab?

I created two files in one I install version 0.21.3, and in the other the same version is installed immediately, how to make the versions in different files different?

Comment: I was looking at the same file:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in python without complicated workarounds.
You could run a subprocess in a different python version using virtual environments via [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for each script.

I advise against it though. Maybe someone can make a good alternative suggestion if you tell us why you need to have different versions of the same library.